# ManyToMany admin field with filter

Tags: django, django-admin

I was trying to get a filter feature for my admin, otherwise it is tough to find the value the data-entry would need to find. Something like this:
[image: what i wanted]

I found that in https://demo.django-blog-zinnia.com/admin/zinnia/entry/add/ (the login info for the site is user: demo, pass: demo)

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please, could you provide some code of your specific problem. That prove how far did you try and it will help other members to understand your problem better, at the time, you will give them a context of your issue. Please, check these links: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Use [Bootstrap-Select Multiple](https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/examples/#multiple-select-boxes)

This is a simple JQuery plug-in that will enable you to select multiple values of data as you have shown in the demo link.

This also gives you the options to search the data-set

In my opinion, this is a bit better for the UI than the style you have shown.

Comment: how do i implement it for django admin?

Comment: sorry for the bother, but i am really newbie on customizing the admin field. All i know is simply how to add models to the admin page, set what fields to be editable, to be listed on index, etc.

Comment: Why are you modifying the admin may I ask?

Comment: some of the fields of these manyToMany have 200++ values, with filter, it is much more easier to get the one the data-entry wanted

Comment: i still haven't figure out how to do it, do i have to create custom backend admin page for that object?

Comment: Create a custom admin page of your own, write a view for it which will retrieve data from the model you want, then implement the bootstrap-select and do as you wish in the view.